# Is there such thing as a functor from the Category of all Groups to that of all binary operations?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, functors

I know that it is possible to define "forgetful" functors that maps the Category of Groups in that of Sets.
Is it possibile to do the the same with binary operations? In other words, is it possible to "forget" the underlying set of a group?

Comment: What's your definition of binary operation?  The usual definition requires a set.  If all you want a binary operation to be is a map from the product category $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}$, then you could forget you have a set.

Comment: A group is formally defined as an ordered pair of two sets, one underlying set G and a particular subset of the cartesian product GxG. I'm thinking of a law that associates two sets to a group.

Comment: No, a group is a pair $(G, \cdot)$ where $\cdot : G\times G\to G$,so $\cdot$ is not a subset of $G\times G$, but rather of $G\times G\times G$ with certain properties. But what would be the category to which you're going ? Moreover, here the name "forgetful" wouldn't be appropriate, since you can recover $G$ from $\cdot$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if a forgetful functor is the correct way to approach the problem of studying groups without regard for their underlying sets (but maybe such a one does exist in the context of what I'm about to suggest). Instead, a natural way to study groups as a collection of operations instead of as sets with extra structure is using the concept of an [algebra over a Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+over+a+Lawvere+theory). You can look [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/operations-and-lawvere-theories/) for an introductory survey. You could also look into [algebraic theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory) in general as a solution to the problem of encoding the binary, and in general $n$-ary, operations of familiar algebraic objects without concern for their underlying sets.